# Induce reachability status check failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring

I have some tools that monitor the status checks of all my organisation's EC2 instances. I'd like to test them by deliberately inducing a failure of the reachability status check (that comes by default with all EC2 instances, pictured in the EC2 console below) on one of my instances - ideally through some means that lets me individually break the `InstanceStatus` version of the check and the `SystemStatus` version.

[image: Screenshot of the EC2 console, showing the reachability status checks.]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I typed your query into Google ("test aws instance status checks") and found [this page on the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=609877) which has two ways to do it.

> An easy way to trigger a status check failure is to disable the
>   default NIC in the instance. For Linux instances,

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

> should do the trick.
>
> Recovery is by adding an additional ENI to the instance and connecting
>   in through that, then bringing the original ENI up with "sudo ifconfig
>   eth0 up".

The same page has this

> I know this is an old post, but I saw a suggestion from another post
>   on [reddit/r/aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5t2tny/how_to_simulate_instance_system_status_check/ddjxcx1).
>   It looks like you can temporarily set a different state for an alarm.
>   I mention temporary because during the next period, the alarm will be
>   re-evaluated for it's new state.
>
> Taking a look at [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html) I think you should be able to do the following:

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state \
  --alarm-name "ec2_system_alarm" \
  --state-value ALARM \
  --state-reason "simulate an ec2 system failure"
```

Comment: This doesn't provide a way to break the system reachability status check, only the instance reachability status check, but is nonetheless useful; +1. (It's not obvious to me whether there even *is* a way to make the system reachability status check fail.)

Comment: System status checks are checks for the underlying hardware. To test that you would need physical access to the AWS data centre.